# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json

I've seen a lot this message error on this forum, but I still got my problem.
Here's the thing: I have an Android app with a Form, I put text on the form and press send, once sent, that's in my data base.
No problem of parsing when the database is in my local server (localhost)

BUT, I have the same database in a real server website, and when I'm trying to send the form JSON just send me "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of "
I've checked, my php files are at the right place, connection variables are the right ones.

Here's my JSON parser :

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `json` string look like?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where can I see that?

Comment: You can do `Log.e("JSON Parser", "JSON String is  " + json);` before you try to convert it to a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Still the same error : but got"JSON String is ". and nothing other, so json is empty .

Comment: 'json' is probably empty because you're not getting it back from the url. How are you calling `makeHttpRequest`? Can you add an example in your question?

Comment: Hum, I've did like that: "public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) { "but what could be the problem? I've just changed the URL it's an other database with same fields so it should work without change anything.I've tested back with my local database it's still working, what's the problem between a local url and a real url for JSON?

Comment: What happens if you call the url in a web browser with the same arguments?

Comment: got that : {"success":0,"message":"required field empty"} , so it confirms that it exists

Comment: Still not working I don't know where the problem is

Comment: It's hard for us to know what is wrong with the web service you're calling without any info. I'd suggest confirming that your code is definitely making the same request (i.e same HTTP method, arguments, e.t.c.) and then removing parts of the requests until you get the smallest request that works, this should help you track down what's causing the service to return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your response as text by`String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);`

Comment: I put that on my JSON parser?

Comment: Could you paste here your JSON string?

Comment: I've put my JSONParser on the first post, where can I find JSON string??

Comment: ok i finally got this: 03-14 12:53:51.730: E/JSON Parser(16125): JSON String is, so it thinks that my string is empty...

Comment: i dont know why but now i've got this : java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground(), never had before